# How to initialize a boost::dynamic_bitset from std::bitset

Tags: c++, bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset

How can I initialize a `boost::dynamic_bitset` from `std::bitset`? The simplest solution is a for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<bitset_size;i++)
    my_dynamic_bitset[i] = my_bitset[i];
```

Is there any shorter or faster way to do this?

Comment: You can use `to_string` and construct boost::dynamic_bitset from string.

Comment: @ForEveR `my_dynamic_bitset.init_from_string(my_bitset.to_string())` wont compile.

Comment: ehm. You should send `string` to constructor. Do you read dynamic_bitset reference?

Comment: @Meysam, Here is what you should use `boost::dynamic_bitset <unsigned char > my_dynamic_bitset(my_bitset.to_string())`.

Comment: @ForEveR & Pooja, Thank you