# convert dynamic_bitset to std::bitset

Tags: boost, std, bitset, std-bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset

I have an application where I need to dynamically allocate a bitset at runtime, so I'm forced to use `boost::dynamic_bitset`. However, for efficiency reasons, I'd like to ultimately use the data as `std::bitset`. How might I go about converting from `boost::dynamic_bitset` to `std::bitset`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to create a std:bitset of the size for your processing.

If you're just dealing with a byte, then

```
std::bitset<8> bitworkarea;
```

Or if you need to have more bits accessed then create a bigger working area.

The post below should alsohelp copying between bitsets.

[How to initialize a boost::dynamic_bitset from std::bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326934/how-to-initialize-a-boostdynamic-bitset-from-stdbitset)